# Deploying Keras model using flask, POST requests always giving same answer

Tags: python, api, flask, keras, deployment

I'm building a Keras model to classify pictures of coral according to the species. The model is functioning well, however when I built a Flask API to access the model I'm always getting the same answer. Currently, the model differentiates between three different corals,and works well when tested outside the API.

The dominant color is being sent accurately. I tried retraining the model but it wouldn't work. When i switched to a different binary model to detect a cat vs a dog it seems to work fine.

I tested the same images on both jupyter and by sending post requests and got very different answers.
Here's the server code

```
import os
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for, jsonify
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import cv2
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import load_model
from keras import backend as K


UPLOAD_FOLDER = './uploads/'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'])
DEBUG = True
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit an empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            image = cv2.imread(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+"/uploads/"+filename)
            color_result = getDominantColor(image)
            coral = coraltype(image)
            #return redirect(url_for('upload_file',filename=filename)), jsonify({"key":
            return jsonify({"MainColor": color_result, "species": coral} )
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>API</title>
    <h1>API Running Successfully</h1>'''

def coraltype(image):
    '''Determines if the image contains a cat or dog'''

    model = load_model('./models/coral_classifier_cnn_1.h5')
    image = cv2.resize(image, (40,40), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    image = image.reshape(1,40,40,3) 
    res = model.predict_classes(image, 1, verbose = 0)
    print(res)
    print(type(res))
    res = str(res)
    K.clear_session()
    return res

def getDominantColor(image):
    '''returns the dominate color among Blue, Green and Reds in the image '''
    B, G, R = cv2.split(image)
    B, G, R = np.sum(B), np.sum(G), np.sum(R)
    color_sums = [B,G,R]
    color_values = {"0": "Blue", "1":"Green", "2": "Red"}
    return color_values[str(np.argmax(color_sums))]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Here's the model

```
from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import os

num_classes = 3
img_rows, img_cols = 40, 40
batch_size = 16

train_data_dir = './corals/train'
validation_data_dir = './corals/validation'

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale=1./255,
      rotation_range=30,
      width_shift_range=0.3,
      height_shift_range=0.3,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      fill_mode='nearest')

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_rows, img_cols),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        shuffle=True)

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        validation_data_dir,
        target_size=(img_rows, img_cols),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        shuffle=False)

model = Sequential()

# Padding = 'same'  results in padding the input such that
# the output has the same length as the original input
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 input_shape= (img_rows, img_cols, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

from keras.optimizers import RMSprop, SGD
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau


checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("/home/deeplearningcv/DeepLearningCV/Trained Models/coral_classifier_cnn_1.h5",
                             monitor="val_loss",
                             mode="min",
                             save_best_only = True,
                             verbose=1)

earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor = 'val_loss', 
                          min_delta = 0, 
                          patience = 3,
                          verbose = 1,
                          restore_best_weights = True)

reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor = 'val_loss',
                              factor = 0.2,
                              patience = 3,
                              verbose = 1,
                              min_delta = 0.0001)

# we put our call backs into a callback list
callbacks = [earlystop, checkpoint, reduce_lr]

# We use a very small learning rate 
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer = RMSprop(lr = 0.001),
              metrics = ['accuracy'])

nb_train_samples = 793
nb_validation_samples = 42
epochs = 10

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = nb_train_samples,
    epochs = epochs,
    callbacks = callbacks,
    validation_data = validation_generator,
    validation_steps = nb_validation_samples)
```

Comment: Don't just copy paste your entire code. Try to debug it to narrow down the problem. If you're convinced that the model is alright, debug the flask code. Are you getting the same values for the dominant colour as well? Look into pdb for Python debugging.

Comment: Should have given more info, my bad. The values for dominant color are changing, tried other ways to load model plus re training the model, still no change.

Comment: does your model work otherwise? what are some performance metrics?